# Blanket implementations of traits with generics

Tags: generics, matrix, rust

I am practicing Rust by implementing matrix math and I'm running into a few snags. I defined the traits that I thought were relevant to a matrix.

```
trait Matrix<T> where T : num::Num  {
    fn dim(&self) -> (usize, usize);
    fn elem(&self, i : usize, j : usize) -> Option<& T>; 
    fn new_const(v: T, rows : usize, cols : usize) -> Self where T : Clone;

    fn same_dim<U>(&self, other: &U) -> bool where U : Matrix<T> {
        self.dim() == other.dim()
    }
}
```

I have a dumb implementation using `Vec<Vec<T>>`. I implemented all of the methods and tested them. They are all working. Now I want to simply add two matrices together. So without adding the row iterator that I know will be required and doing an add implementation that I know is going to be incorrect I put the following.

```
impl <T, U> Add for U where T: num::Num, U: Matrix<T> {
    type Output = U;

    fn add(self, _rhs: U) -> U {
        U::new_const(T::zero(), 5, 5)
    }
}
```

but I get

```
lib.rs:41:7: 41:8 error: the type parameter `T` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates [E0207]
lib.rs:41 impl <T, U> Add for U where T: num::Num, U: Matrix<T> {
                ^
lib.rs:41:7: 41:8 help: run `rustc --explain E0207` to see a detailed explanation
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `matrix`.
To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
Compilation failed.
```

T does seem constrained to me. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`T` isn't constrained by the information the compiler can see at the use-site of the implementation. By having `trait Matrix<T>`, a single type can be a matrix over multiple element types, that is, it's perfectly legal for someone to have both `impl Matrix<u8> for Foo` and `impl Matrix<u16> for Foo` in the same program. If this happens, then `Foo + Foo` (i.e. a use of the `Add` implementation) can't be sure which `T` to use: both `T = u8` and `T = u16` work.

I think the best way to solve this is to remove the `T` type parameter: a given type is only a matrix over one sort of element (even if it's generic), e.g. `Vec<Vec<T>>` is a matrix over `T`, nothing else. This is like [`Iterator`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html): a given type can only yield one type of element.

In code, this looks like:

```
trait Matrix {
    type Elem: num::Num;

    fn dim(&self) -> (usize, usize);
    fn elem(&self, i: usize, j: usize) -> Option<&Self::Elem>;
    // ...
}
```

The `Add` implementation then becomes

```
impl<U> Add for U where U: Matrix {
    type Output = U;

    fn add(self, _rhs: U) -> U {
        U::new_const(U::Elem::zero(), 5, 5)
    }
}
```

However, this also doesn't work, as it hits coherence problems. The compiler can't be sure that this implementation of `Add` doesn't overlap with other implementations of `Add`, since one could implement `Matrix` for a type that already has an `Add` implementation in some way. One can work around this by making a wrapper type, and using the `Matrix` trait instead as a "backing storage" trait, i.e. it "just" controls the internal representation.

```
struct Matrix<T: Storage> {
    x: T
}
trait Storage { // renamed `Matrix` trait
    type Elem;
    fn dim(&self) -> (usize, usize);
    // ...
}
```

The `Matrix` type then becomes the place to add more methods and trait implementations etc.