# Implementing a generic incrementable trait in Rust

Tags: rust, traits, generic-programming

I'm trying to understand how to implement a generic trait in Rust.

While I've seen a number of examples, the examples are too tied to a specific use (e.g. [genomic mutators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35525505/how-to-restrict-generic-implementation-of-a-trait-in-rust)) for me to be able to understand at this point in my Rust development.

Instead, here's a simple example based on something fairly universal--incrementing:

```
trait Incrementable {
    fn post_inc(&mut self) -> Self;
    fn post_inc_by(&mut self, n: usize) -> Self;
}

impl Incrementable for usize {
    fn post_inc(&mut self) -> Self {
        let tmp = *self;
        *self += 1;
        tmp
    }

    //"Overload" for full generalizability
    fn post_inc_by(&mut self, n: usize) -> Self {
        let tmp = *self;
        *self += n;
        tmp
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut result = 0;
    assert!(result.post_inc() == 0);
    assert!(result == 1);

    assert!(result.post_inc_by(3) == 1);
    assert!(result == 4);
}
```

The above code works, but is lacking because it isn't generalizable to all numeric types without writing a lot of boilerplate code.

In my attempts to generalize the above code, I've gotten into fights with the type system, borrow checker or been forced down a path of implementing `FromPrimitive` for every type I want to support in my generic version (effectively putting me back to square one).

Can you help me understand how to implement `Incrementable` generically,
 such that `post_inc()` and `post_inc_by()` work for at least all integer and float types, ideally without having to write an implementation for each type?

I am hoping the answer will help me see how traits, implementations, types and associated types can work together in a more straightforward use case than I've been able to come across.

I'm on Rust 1.16.0.

Comment: [I typed this up on my tablet on the train on my way home from work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=71f451a4a04d61ad613806fd76a2cc96&version=nightly&backtrace=0). Without a proper setup to Google further thats all I could come up with.. but unfortunately it requires not only the nightly compiler but a deprecated trait since 1.11. Not a great example for you perhaps but shows _one way_ I guess.

Comment: Thank you @SimonWhitehead.  You're right about not wanting to use deprecated features, but it is still educational to see how you put this together.  For the moment Self::one() does indeed work.  Ultimately I want to add a more flexible method `post_inc_by(n: usize)` to increment by `n` rather than just 1, though, so if you have any ideas on that I would be grateful. (I've added this to the question.)
I'll work through the implementation you've provided, though and see if I can use non-deprecated equivalents.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with macros, following [what the std did](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/core/up/src/libcore/ops.rs.html#255-268):

```
trait Incrementable {
    fn post_inc(&mut self) -> Self;
    fn post_inc_by(&mut self, n: Self) -> Self;
}

macro_rules! post_inc_impl {
    ($($t:ty)*) => ($(
        impl Incrementable for $t {
            fn post_inc(&mut self) -> Self {
                self.post_inc_by(1 as Self)
            }

            fn post_inc_by(&mut self, n: Self) -> Self {
                let tmp = *self;
                *self += n;
                tmp
            }
        }
    )*)
}

post_inc_impl! { usize u8 u16 u32 u64 isize i8 i16 i32 i64 f32 f64 }

fn main() {
    let mut result = 0;
    assert!(result.post_inc() == 0);
    assert!(result == 1);

    assert!(result.post_inc_by(3) == 1);
    assert!(result == 4);
}
```

It is possible without macros if you use the [`num` crate](https://crates.io/crates/num):

```
extern crate num;

use num::Num;

trait Incrementable<T: Num> {
    fn post_inc(&mut self) -> Self;
    fn post_inc_by(&mut self, n: T) -> Self;
}

impl<T: Num + std::ops::AddAssign<T> + Copy> Incrementable<T> for T {
    fn post_inc(&mut self) -> T {
        let tmp = *self;
        *self += T::one();
        tmp
    }

    fn post_inc_by(&mut self, n: T) -> Self {
        let tmp = *self;
        *self += n;
        tmp
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the reference to std implementation.  That is a good idea to look there to see how similar problems have been solved.

Comment: @bRadGibson I'm not even good with macros, but plenty of things are implemented with them in the `std` - and if it does it like that, it usually means it's a good idea :).

Comment: Either it's a good idea, or it's just the best way we have currently ;-)

Comment: Wow--very nice, @ljedrz.  The solution you came up with using the `num` crate is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

[@Simon Whitehead's example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=71f451a4a04d61ad613806fd76a2cc96&version=nightly&backtrace=0) can easily be adapted for stable Rust:

```
trait Incrementable: Copy + std::ops::AddAssign<Self> {
    fn one() -> Self;

    fn post_inc(&mut self) -> Self {
        self.post_inc_by(Self::one())
    }

    fn post_inc_by(&mut self, n: Self) -> Self {
        let tmp = *self;
        *self += n;
        tmp
    }
}

impl Incrementable for u8  { fn one() -> Self {1} }
impl Incrementable for u16 { fn one() -> Self {1} }
impl Incrementable for u32 { fn one() -> Self {1} }
impl Incrementable for u64 { fn one() -> Self {1} }
impl Incrementable for i8  { fn one() -> Self {1} }
impl Incrementable for i16 { fn one() -> Self {1} }
impl Incrementable for i32 { fn one() -> Self {1} }
impl Incrementable for i64 { fn one() -> Self {1} }
impl Incrementable for f32 { fn one() -> Self {1.0} }
impl Incrementable for f64 { fn one() -> Self {1.0} }
```

While you need to do the implementation for each type, each of them is extremely simple.

You can also use a macro to hide repetitive implementations:

```
macro_rules! impl_Incrementable{
    ($($m:ty),*) => {$( impl Incrementable for $m  { fn one() -> Self { 1 as $m } })*}
}

impl_Incrementable!{u8, u16, u32, u64, i8, i16, i32, i64, f32, f64}
```

Comment: Nice! I considered this shortly after posting my comment but ... typing code on an Android tablet that is about 4 years old is a terrible terrible experience :D

Comment: You don't need `Self::one()`, `self.post_inc_by(1 as Self)` would work just as well.

Comment: @ljedrz the complier complains when I change `Self::one()` to `1 as Self` with "error: non-scalar cast: 'i32' as 'Self'"'.  Ideas?

Comment: @aSpex This is a nice solution, especially the macro for eliminating the need to write all those type-specific implementations, thank you.  Can you explain why in `main()`, I can write `post_inc_by(3)`, but in `post_inc()`, writing `post_inc_by(1)` gives `expected Self, found integral variable` compile error?

Comment: @bRadGibson this works when you implement it within a macro. I'll undelete my similar answer so you can see it: [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41671656/1870153).

Comment: @ljedrz ah--I tried using it in post_inc(). Unhappy compiler.  Yes, I see aSpex used it in the macro solution above.

Comment: @bRadGibson There is no implicit type casting in Rust. So the compiler won't convert `1` to the `Self`. If you try `self.post_inc_by(1 as Self)` it complains `non-scalar cast`. `Self` can be any type which impl `Copy` and `AddAssign`. There is no way to bound `Self` so that `1 as Self` always been valid.

Comment: @bRadGibson Sorry does not work for `i8`. This is playground link if you interested: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e39a122fe31a006afa23ecc1b63a19ae&version=stable&backtrace=0

Answer (score 3):

The types that we can increment need to

1. know the operator and `+=` (`AddAssign`)
2. define a value for the "one"-element
3. be copyable as we want to keep the old un-incremented value.

Point 1. and 3. we can assure by using a trait bound, for point 2. we can set up a trait that has the function `one() -> self`.

So here is a working example:

```
// We need to know the operator "+="
use std::ops::AddAssign;

// The trait needs a type parameter
trait Incrementable<T> {
    fn post_inc(&mut self) -> Self;
    fn post_inc_by(&mut self, n: T) -> Self;
}

// We need a trait which tells us the "one" value for a type
trait Increment {
    fn one() -> Self;
}

// We need to implement the Increment trait for every type
// we want to increment.
impl Increment for usize {
    fn one() -> usize {
        1
    }
}

// Finally we implement the Increment trait generically for all types that
// * know the operator "+=" AddAssign
// * are copyable
// * implement our Increment trait, so that we know their "one" value
impl<T: AddAssign + Increment + Copy> Incrementable<T> for T {
    fn post_inc(&mut self) -> Self {
        let tmp = *self;
        *self += T::one();
        tmp
    }

    //"Overload" for full generalizability
    fn post_inc_by(&mut self, n: T) -> Self {
        let tmp = *self;
        *self += n;
        tmp
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut result = 0;
    assert!(result.post_inc() == 0);
    assert!(result == 1);

    assert!(result.post_inc_by(3) == 1);
    assert!(result == 4);
}
```

You don't have to write an implementation of `Incrementable` for each type, but you do have to implement the trait that supplies the `one()` function. You can't get away without that, because for non numerical types it is not obvious what "increment by one" means.

I kept everything in a generic implementation that can be implemented generically. The exception is the `T::one()`, so no boiler-plate code needed except this one trivial function for each type.

Comment: @JohannesMueller: +1 I appreciate the clear step-by-step breakdown, especially why the Copy trait is needed.

Comment: @bRadGibson FWIW, I think this answer has the best *explanation* of why you have to implement the trait multiple times, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41671697/155423) has the nicer implementation.

Comment: Excellent answer, shows that there's nothing really magical in the `num` crate (for this simple purpose). Also, consider using `Clone` in preference to `Copy`. It only requires the explicit call to `clone`, e.g. `let tmp = self.clone()`, and instantly buys the support for arbitrary-width types, such as [`BigInt`](http://rust-num.github.io/num/num_bigint/struct.BigInt.html). The primitive types will still work because `Copy` automatically implies `Clone`.

Comment: Nice.  Note that bigint and biguint also don't implement AddAssign or SubAssign, so there would be a bit more work to get them into the family.  Still, I like the idea and will explore it further.  Thank you!